# How do you display data from database into datagridview in C#?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am trying to pull data from my SQL table called `CurrencyConversionAuditing` but for some reason it doesn't work. I have created a button, so when I click it, it displays everything from that table.

So my code currently is:

```
string ConnectionString;
SqlConnection con;

ConnectionString = @"Data Source = (localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB; Initial Catalog = myDatabase; Integrated Security = True"; };

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlDataAdapter sdf = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM CurrencyConversionAuditing", con);
    DataTable sd = new DataTable();
    sdf.Fill(sd);

    dataGridView1.DataSource = sd;
}
```

When I run this, the error I am getting is:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'Fill: SelectCommand.Connection property has not been initialized.'

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: You have to create a **new** `SqlConnection`, pass the connection string, and **open** it before you can use it in the `SqlDataAdapter`. Also, close and dispose it when you finish.

Comment: what do you mean 'create a new SqlConnection', I already have a connection string, isn't that correct?

Comment: You have to get an ADO.NET book or follow a tutorial; this stuff is too complicated to learn by trial and error.

Comment: You need to do: `SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);` then `con.open();` and when you finish, you should `con.close();` and `con.Dispose();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your con object is not initialized. Make sure to initialize it first as:

```
con = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
```

and you have to open the con:

```
con.Open();
```

and do not forget to close the con:

```
con.Close();
```

Your code should be:

```
string ConnectionString;
SqlConnection con;

ConnectionString = @"Data Source = (localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB; Initial Catalog = myDatabase; Integrated Security = True"; };

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    con = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
    con.Open();
    SqlDataAdapter sdf = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM CurrencyConversionAuditing", con);
    DataTable sd = new DataTable();
    sdf.Fill(sd);
    con.Close();
    dataGridView1.DataSource = sd;
}
```